# Validate Email Domain (Top level domains)

Tags: c#, .net

How could I check if a string is a valid email domain name (eg: google.com) without making external calls or using regular expressions? I would like the string to contain only the top level domains (eg: google.com and not web.google.com). This should also support other top level domains such as google.co.uk or xyz.org or xyz.edu.

Edit:
I am trying to check if it complies to a specific format and not checking the existence. For example , f2363.com might not exist but it complies with the rules of a valid top level domain.

Comment: What does "validation" mean in this context? What are you trying to ascertain?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am just trying to check if it complies to a specific format and not checking the existence. For example , `f2363.com` might not exist but it complies with the rules of a valid top level domain.

Comment: So what you're really asking is "does C# have a thing that can tell me if a string value is also a valid domain FQDN"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I wanted to see if C# has any library to check if a string is a valid top level domain.

Comment: Not completely clear what you mean by "top level domain"? Why is "google.co.uk" acceptable, but "web.google.com" is not?

Comment: Hi @KlausGütter, sorry to be clear, I didn't want to support subdomains but wanted to ensure the second level domains are valid. I used the list of domains provided by PublicSuffix to do this validation.

Answer (score 1):

In C# there are a few ways you can check that a Uri is a valid format without REGEX but not specifically that it is only a TLD. So for example you can check to see if a Uri is valid with `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString()` [for which the .Net 7 doc is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring?view=net-7.0#system-uri-iswellformeduristring(system-string-system-urikind)).

Keep in mind this answer assumes you absolutely do not want to use any of the various helpful Nuget packages or other systems like REGEX for this. This is not a preferred solution and its accuracy is ***highly questionable***, but I am trying to stay true to your "without making external calls or using regular expressions" statement.

---

Its use is simple:

```cs
string url = "google.com";
Console.WriteLine(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

output:

```
True
```

---

You may be able to mix `UriKind` types to detect TLDs though. ***I'm not sure of the accuracy in doing this*** myself but if a Uri is well formatted relative and not well formatted absolute it may give you a better indication.

```cs
string url = "google.com";
bool isTLD = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Relative) && !Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute);
Console.WriteLine(isTLD);
```

output:

```
True
```

```cs
string url = "https://www.google.com";
bool isTLD = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Relative) && !Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute);
Console.WriteLine(isTLD);
```

output:

```
False
```

Comment: To be extra super very clear; I would not trust or use this code in any production setting or any place where money is on the line. I would probably recommend you learn to love REGEX for the horrific monster of usefulness it is.